# Cupy memory error on Google Colab with GPU - but only the second time I run the code

Tags: python, dask, cupy

I am trying to do a matrix multiplication on two large arrays using Cupy since it is significantly faster (about 100x) than using the CPU. My problem is that it works the first time I run it, but then the second time and so on it gives me a memory error. It is a step in a loop so this is a problem, I can't be restarting the runtime each time.

Here is the reproducible code with same array size and data type:

```
import cupy as cp
import datetime

cp.get_default_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()
cp.get_default_pinned_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()

x = cp.random.uniform(-1,1,size = (3000,300000))
w = cp.random.uniform(-1,1,size= (300000,1000))

start = datetime.now()
ans = cp.matmul(x,w)
stop = datetime.now()
print(stop-start)
```

Here is the error I get when I run it for the second time in the same runtime:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OutOfMemoryError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-43db33b58bc8> in <module>()
      2 cp.get_default_pinned_memory_pool().free_all_blocks()
      3 
----> 4 x = cp.random.uniform(-1,1,size = (3000,300000))
      5 w = cp.random.uniform(-1,1,size= (300000,1000))
      6 

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cupy/creation/basic.py in empty(shape, dtype, order)
     20 
     21     """
---> 22     return cupy.ndarray(shape, dtype, order=order)
     23 
     24 

cupy/core/core.pyx in cupy.core.core.ndarray.__init__()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.alloc()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.MemoryPool.malloc()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool.malloc()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory.SingleDeviceMemoryPool._malloc()

cupy/cuda/memory.pyx in cupy.cuda.memory._try_malloc()

OutOfMemoryError: Out of memory allocating 7,200,000,000 bytes (allocated so far: 9,624,000,000 bytes).
```

Can this be fixed? I'm trying to clear the GPU memory in the first two lines but not sure if thats correct. Maybe using a dask array would work instead? But can that be done while still using the GPU for speed?

Comment: Dask arrays do support GPUs, but it may not be relevant here. You're trying to allocate memory for two arrays. The first is 3000*300000*8 bytes (7.2 GB), and the second is 300000*1000*8 bytes (2.4 GB). These combine to be 9.6 GB. On iteration two, you try to free all memory. But Python is holding references to your existing arrays. Also, because assignment happens right to left, before Python can replace `x` it's going out of memory trying to allocate another 7.2 GB. Can you explicitly `del` your arrays in the loop?

Comment: Yes I can. I've tried using ```del``` before re-running the code but it still results in a memory error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using CuPy-backed Dask arrays would probably be fine here.  You would want to make sure to use the single-threaded scheduler (`.compute(scheduler="single-threaded")` .  Assuming that [you're making your arrays in such a way that Dask can load in chunks at a time](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#load-data-with-dask)then Dask will probably be able to load in a few chunks, do some of the computation, throw out intermediates, and then load in other chunks.